# Adaptation of the ICD2

Tags: microcontroller, pic, debugging

I'm trying to adapt the ICD2 so that it can be used with a microcontroller family (dsPIC33F) that has a 3.3V supply.
Projects using the ICD2 must be 5V. How can I do this?

Comment: You might have better luck if you didn't assume that everyone knows what an ICD2 is, and if you were a bit more specific about what you were trying to do.

Comment: ICD2 = "In-circuit debugger 2" for those wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this from Microchip the ICD2 works across 2.0V to 6.0V. http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=dv164005

However, AFAIK the ICD2 is no longer supported by Microchip, and you should upgrade to an ICD3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes exactly that, but I was wondering if there was some way to make the ICD2 works in accordance with the ICD3.

It would to place a voltage regulator to change the output voltage for 3.3V which is the microcontroller I am using, ie make a circuit to increase the ICD2 (external board). However they have the ICD2 signals from sensors, which is a little more complicated, a way perhaps would be the voltage divider. But it is a risk, it can damage the microcontroller. = (

Anyway, thank you for attention!